# Knockout - Cancel a Change Event?

Tags: jquery, mvvm, knockout.js

I have a checkbox bound to an observable on a view model.  I have a requirement to essentially pop up an "Are you sure?" confirmation prompt if the user changes it from true to false.  I'm having a horrible time figuring out the best place to make the change "cancelable" . . .

1) jQuery handler for click event
2) Viewmodel internal subscribe "beforeChange"
3) Viewmodel internal subscribe (normal)

In any case, I'd vastly prefer to have the chance to cancel the change outright than react to the change, potentially reverting it back to its previous value if need be.

Does Knockout's subscribe event give you the chance to cancel a change?  Any insight would be appreciated.  Thanks!

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Here is a simple option using jQuery's stopImmediatePropagation:

http://jsfiddle.net/rniemeyer/cBvXM/

```
<input type="checkbox" data-bind="click: confirmCheck, checked: myvalue" />
```

js:

```
var viewModel = {
    myvalue: ko.observable(false),
    confirmCheck: function(data, event) {
        if (!confirm("Are you sure?")) {
            event.stopImmediatePropagation();            
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }
};
```

Comment: Oh, my gosh!  That is fantastically helpful.  I never knew about jQuery's stopImmediatePropagation().  While I usually try to avoid referencing jQuery stuff outside of the core viewModel, this is a great solution for my problem.  Thank you again!

Comment: In my case `event.stopImmediatePropagation` didn't stop the value from changing in the ko viewModel. I had to set the value again: `var cb = event.target; ... data.myvalue(!cb.checked);`

Comment: The order of the data-bind is *very* important in this case. If you bind the value *before* the event, the value binding executes first. If the event is bound, it will execute first and stop the propagation. See this fiddle to see it broken: http://jsfiddle.net/8AuVj/

Comment: @Jimmy Bosse - This is worth putting in the answer, exactly the problem I was having.

Comment: This will miss anyone making a change using the keyboard; make sure you catch those events as well if you take this route.

Answer (score 15):

Because of the problems commented in @RP Niemeyer answer, I've just implemented this extender:

```js
ko.extenders.confirmable = function(target, options) {
    var message = options.message;
    var unless = options.unless || function() { return false; }
    //create a writeable computed observable to intercept writes to our observable
    var result = ko.computed({
        read: target,  //always return the original observables value
        write: function(newValue) {
            var current = target();

            //ask for confirmation unless you don't have
            if (unless() || confirm(message)) {
                target(newValue);
            } else {
              target.notifySubscribers(current);
            }
        }
    }).extend({ notify: 'always' });

    //return the new computed observable
    return result;
};
```

You can then apply that to your model like this:

```
var viewModel = {
    myvalue: ko.observable(false).extend({confirmable: "Are you sure?"});
}
```

And, if there was a case in which not to ask for confirmation (in this silly example, we'll skip confirmation during March), you can do:

```
var viewModel = {
    myvalue: ko.observable(false).extend({confirmable: { message: "Are you sure?", unless: function() { return new Date().getMonth() == 2 }} });
}
```

Comment: Magnificent! It can be used in many scenarios. Just one thing, it should be used like this: `.extend({ confirmable: { message: "Are you sure?", unless: function() { return new Date().getMonth() == 2 }} });`

Comment: Nice! That's a magnificently engineered idea.