# Knockout.js - Change other observables in viewmodel from extender or other way to do something similar

Tags: knockout.js, knockout-2.0

I've been doing some simple knockout things before, but this one feels a more complicated.
A client wishes to be able to control the number of order rows in a form with the help of a dropdown (I asked why they didn't want a regular add button, but they said this would give them better overview that everything was filled out...).

I have an observable holding the value from the dropdown and an observableArray to hold the order rows, but I had to confirm the selection was intended when the new value is less than the previous.

So I started scouring the internet for tips and tricks how to accomplish this.
First I found [this "confirmable" extender](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21482696/2814279). It helped me show a confirm dialog if the number of rows they selected was less than the previous value, but I found no way to interact with other observables in the viewmodel from it.

So I Google'd some more and found [the first answer from Michael Best here](https://github.com/knockout/knockout/pull/520). With the "subscribeChanged" function I could now (after the confirmable extender did its part) add or remove rows to the observable array of order rows.

However. I would like for there to be some better way to accomplish this in order to not have the almost exact code in more than one place. Because now I have this code in the extender

```
if (!isValidateInteger(current) && isValidateInteger(newValue)) {
    target(newValue);
    // TODO: Add rows to vm.orderRows so the count reflects newValue
}
```

and this code in subscribeChanged function

```
if (!isValidateInteger(current) && isValidateInteger(newValue)) {
    // NOTE: Add rows to vm.orderRows so the count reflects newValue
    difference = (newValueInt - currentInt);
    message += '<br />Add ' + difference + ' row(s).';
    for (var i = 0; i < difference; i++) {
        vm.orderRows().push(new OrderRow());
    }
    vm.orderRows.valueHasMutated();
}
```

I've put together [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/BVtd7/) with an excerpt of the code I have today.

I know some of the if-statements don't need to be there, but they're for debugging purpose at the moment. I will look at which to remove when the functionality is completed and tested, but any pointers (even ones not pertaining the question) are welcome.

Thanks in advance, Ludvig

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a computed observable to both use confirm and update if ok:

```
vm.enhancedNumberOfOrderRows = ko.computed({
    read: vm.numberOfOrderRows,
    write: function(newValue) {
        //do all your checks, update vm.numberOfOrderRows only if you want
    }
});
```

See the exemple: http://jsfiddle.net/v3EAz/2/

**EDIT:** You have to call `vm.numberOfOrderRows.valueHasMutated();` if user canceled to update the value of the select.

See: http://jsfiddle.net/v3EAz/3/

Comment: But if you click cancel the dropdown still stays at the "new value". As in if you select 2 it will add 2 rows. Then you select 1 and click cancel, the dropdown will still show 1 even if no rows are removed. This is close to what I'm looking for tho :)

Comment: Answer edited. Indeed even if the value of the observable does not change, the select keep its new value. You can call `vm.numberOfOrderRows.valueHasMutated();` in that case.

Comment: I like this answer. Keeps the requested functionality and removes 1 step. Thanks for the quick help

Answer (score 0):

An extender may not be the best fit for your scenario.  Seems like it's making you jump through unnecessary hoops and the extender logic is specific to your viewmodel/screen, it's not a generic extender that could be reused in other situations.

A simpler approach might be to use the knockout observable's **[subscribe](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/observables.html#explicitly-subscribing-to-observables)** function to listen for changes to `numberOfOrderRows` and react accordingly.

```
var vm = {
    numberOfOrderRows: ko.observable(''),
    orderRows: ko.observableArray(),
};

vm.numberOfOrderRows.subscribe(
... todo write a numberOfOrderRowsChanged handler function to do the following:
1) validate the new value
2) perform any user confirmation logic
3) if successful, update the orderRows observable
4) if unsuccessful, restore the previous value to numberOfOrderRows
```

Comment: But Ludvig does not want to update viewmodel if user canceled on the confirmation

Comment: Like GôTô wrote I need to confirm the selection was indeed on purpose. How would you go about writing this handler function? The reason I used the extender was cause it was among the first hits in the search for code which let me "abort" if the user clicked cancel on the confirmation. I found another subscribe function which had access to both the old and the new value, but if I remember correct it had already set the new value.